# How can i sort array in Javascript based on the first characters of the string element of the array ? - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i am this array:

```
var notifiche_eq= ["10/avdvidv","15/jcbscisb","7/ciudsu"];
```

and i would this output:

```
["15/jcbscisb","10/avdvidv","7/ciudsu"]
```

so based on numeric characters  of each element.

I tried this code but doesn't work:

```
var notifiche_eq= ["10/avdvidv","15/jcbscisb","7/ciudsu"];

notifiche_eq.sort(function(a, b) {
    var milliA= notifiche_eq[a].split('/');
    var milliB= notifiche_eq[b].split('/');

    milliA= (milliA[0])+0;
    milliB= (milliB[0])+0;

    if(milliB- milliA){
     return b-a;
    }

}); 

alert(notifiche_eq);
```

here there's jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/13tLjqc0/8/

I hope you can help me and sorry for my english :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `notifiche_eq[a]`. `a` is already your item.

I optimized your code, so that it handles `>`, `<` and `==`

```js
var notifiche_eq= ["10/avdvidv","15/jcbscisb","7/ciudsu"];

notifiche_eq.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (+a.split('/')[0] > +b.split('/')[0] ? -1 : (+a.split('/')[0] < +b.split('/')[0] ? 1 : 0));
}); 

console.log(notifiche_eq);
```

Version without any ternary operators like asked in the comments :

```js
var notifiche_eq= ["10/avdvidv","15/jcbscisb","7/ciudsu"];

notifiche_eq.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(+a.split('/')[0] > +b.split('/')[0]) return -1;
  else if(+a.split('/')[0] < +b.split('/')[0]) return 1;
  else return 0;
}); 

console.log(notifiche_eq);
```

Comment: please can you show me code not using ternary operator ? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Split by `/`, take the first element and convert it to number by using `+`

```js
var notifiche_eq= ["10/avdvidv", "15/jcbscisb", "7/ciudsu"];
notifiche_eq.sort((a, b) => +b.split('/')[0] - +a.split('/')[0]);
console.log(notifiche_eq);
```

Comment: Good answer, you should perhaps add an explanation about why `notifiche_eq[a]` is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

`a` is already the **item of the array**, **instead of its index** so this line is wrong

```
var milliA= notifiche_eq[a].split('/');
```

Instead just simply

- `split` the item of the array
- get first index value
- convert that to `number` using unary `+`

i.e.

```
notifiche_eq.sort(function(a, b) {
  return +b.split('/')[0] - +a.split('/')[0];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Issues you had...

- `notifiche_eq[a]` and `notifiche_eq[b]` should be just a and b.
- Just return b-a.

```js
var notifiche_eq= ["10/avdvidv","15/jcbscisb","7/ciudsu"];

notifiche_eq = notifiche_eq.sort(function(a, b) {
    var milliA= a.split('/');
    var milliB= b.split('/');

    milliA= +milliA[0];
    milliB= +milliB[0];

    return milliB - milliA;

}); 

console.log(notifiche_eq);
```

You can do some fancy things on your code to make it look good... like..

```
notifiche_eq.sort((a, b) => +b.split('/')[0] - +a.split('/')[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var notifiche_eq = ["10/avdvidv", "15/jcbscisb", "7/ciudsu"];

// es5
notifiche_eq.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.split('/').shift() - a.split('/').shift()
});
// es6
notifiche_eq.sort((a, b) => b.split('/').shift() - a.split('/').shift());

console.log(notifiche_eq)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression for getting the starting digits of the string.

```js
var notifiche_eq = ["10/avdvidv","15/jcbscisb","7/ciudsu"];

notifiche_eq.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getValue(s) { return s.match(/^\d+/)[0]; }
    return getValue(b) - getValue(a);
});

console.log(notifiche_eq);
```